# Can somebody tell me the difference between these two parts of codes

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to read wordpress codes to have a deep insight about how things work, and also because I need to put my hand into it for special reasons, but I got stuck in this, hope some of you guys can explain the difference between these for me:

```
if ( file_exists( ABSPATH . 'wp-config.php') )
```

and

```
if ( file_exists( dirname(ABSPATH) . '/wp-config.php' )
```

Many thanks

Comment: rtm (http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php), `dirname` gives the name of the directory containing the directory you pass to it, so if `ABSPATH` is for exmaple `/var/www`, `dirname(ABSPATH)` is `/var/`

Comment: What may help you figure this out as well is knowing what `ABSPATH` is. `ABSPATH` is a PHP constant defined by Wordpress. It should contain a url, and is often checked by themes and plugins to prevent direct file access. If `ABSPATH` isn't defined, we don't run our code, because we know Worpdress core isn't loaded (or it would be defined).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're looking at [`wp-load.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-load.php), these pieces of code do what their associated comments say:

```
if ( file_exists( ABSPATH . 'wp-config.php') ) {

        /** The config file resides in ABSPATH */
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-config.php' );

} elseif ( file_exists( dirname(ABSPATH) . '/wp-config.php' ) && ! file_exists( dirname(ABSPATH) . '/wp-settings.php' ) ) {

        /** The config file resides one level above ABSPATH but is not part of another install */
        require_once( dirname(ABSPATH) . '/wp-config.php' );
```

That is, they're trying to find the `wp-config.php` file.

As described in [Hardening WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress#Securing_wp-config.php), one option you have for increasing the security of your WordPress installation is to move your `wp-config.php` file one level above the root of your WordPress installation. This is because you can then configure your web sever not to serve any files above the standard WordPress root (where `index.php` lives, so has to be accessible from the web.) That makes it a little less likely that someone can see the content of your `wp-config.php`, which has important things like your database password in it.

So, [given that](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress#Securing_wp-config.php):

> Note that wp-config.php can be stored ONE directory level above the WordPress (where wp-includes resides) installation. Also, make sure that only you (and the web server) can read this file (it generally means a 400 or 440 permission).

...WordPress uses the code you're seeing to first check if there's a `wp-config.php` file at the absolute path of your WordPress installation, i.e. your root WordPress directory, `ABSPATH`, but if there isn't, it uses the [`dirname`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) method to go one step up, by checking for a `wp-config.php` file in the directory that *contains* the root WordPress directory.

Comment: Though I still don't get what you were saying, I really appreciate your reply.